# helper function always returns false in form validation callback

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have regular expression custom helper function in codeigniter, which I am using as call back function in form validation.

When I use the callback function inside the controller it works fine , but when I make it a helper function it's not working, I suspect that the parameter I pass to helper function is not set.

Why am I getting return false every time I input the username field?

controller

```
public function add_user(){

    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');


    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', "required|min_length[8]|max_length[16]|trim|callback_alpha_num_dot|is_unique[user.username]");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[16]|trim|alpha_numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('is_unique', "The $username is already taken");
    //$this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_num_dot', "Special characrters are not allowed");
    $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_num_dot', "return false");

    if(  $this->form_validation->run() == FALSE ){

        echo "wrong";
    }else{
        echo "GOOD TO GO";
    }
}
```

helper

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( !function_exists('alpha_num_dot')){

    function alpha_num_dot($str){

        if(isset($str)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }            

        // if(  preg_match("/^[a-z0-9.]+$/i", $str) ){
        //     return true;
        // }else{

        //     return false;
        // }
    }
}    
?>
```

Comment: Is it running and returning a boolean `false` value, or are you getting your "return false" string?

Comment: You can simply create a local alpha_dot_num method in your controller that uses your helper. The Call back is expected to be in the controller as its looking for $this->alpha_dot_num($str) and not the plain helper function name. So create the local callback and launch whatever helpers etc you need.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw hi, seems like his is the only solution , thanks for reminding.